# How can I select an id that has the lowest value in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is what I'm doing

> SELECT * FROM pacient_export WHERE  (idpacient_nit IN (SELECT
>   idpacient FROM treatment WHERE date_treatment < CURDATE() - INTERVAL
>   180 DAY) OR idpacient_nit IN (SELECT idpacient FROM report7))  AND
>   idpacient_nit IN (SELECT idpacient FROM report7 WHERE charge < 50)
>
> SELECT * FROM pacient_export WHERE  (idpacient_nit IN (SELECT
>   idpacient FROM treatment WHERE date_treatment < CURDATE() - INTERVAL
>   180 DAY) OR idpacient_nit IN (SELECT idpacient FROM report7))  AND
>   idpacient_nit IN (SELECT idpacient FROM report7 WHERE charge >= 50)

The problem is that in table **report7** a pacient can appear several times, it will select the same pacient several times...how can I select the lowest **charge** value in table **report7** for each pacient?

```
For example 
table: report7 
pacient | charge 
101 | 32 
101 | 92 

Results: 
pacient | charge 
101 | 32
```

THanks!!

Comment: use `MIN()` or `LIMIT 1` or `DISTINCT`?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT idpacient FROM report7 WHERE charge >= 50` will select each matching patient ID only once.

Comment: I cant use MIN because it displays this error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"......SELECT DISTINCT doesnt work since if the pacient has charge < 50 it will display 1 result and if the pacient has charge > 50 it will also display 1 result